# Picking the right ItemsSource container

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, itemssource

I have a UserControl I've written to display a few properties from a custom object.  There are multiple instances of these objects so I have an ObservableCollection of them so I can set them as an ItemsSource binding to a ListView.  Now I can get an instance of this UserControl show up for each instance of my class in my ListView.

The problem is I don't really want the behavior of a ListView.  I don't want the user to be able to select the entire UserControl.  In fact, the user should be able to select individual elements in the UserControl.

I thought about just using a StackPanel to put these UserControls in, but it doesn't have an ItemesSource property.  Is there an easy way to make this happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace your `ListView` with an `ItemsControl` and set the `ItemTemplate` to a suitable `DataTemplate` for your objects. You can set the `ItemsPanel` if you want to change how the panel lays out the items.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

See this [example](http://www.galasoft.ch/mydotnet/articles/article-2007041201.aspx)

Comment: Excellent.  I had to add a ScrollViewer to the ItemsControl template, but that was no big deal.  Other than that I was able to just replace ListView with ItemsControl.  Thank you.